# DataGrid CheckboxColumn

Tags: c#, datagrid, checkbox

I´ve got a DataGrid with some data, which I fill like this:

```
dgBuchung.DataContext = dataset;
dgBuchung.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

One Column has the values "Yes" or "No". I need to show them as Checkboxes. 
I read a lot about CheckboxColumns and Binding, but nothing about a solution with my type of filling.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changes this property with return type boolean (True and False).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with that?

Comment: I want to say that currently you have a property(I think) string type of value  "Yes" or "No" so change it to boolean type.